# How to join/merge date column from different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 different CTEs(a,b,c) which have columns date, id, and value. Only the value column has different values in it. Date and Id will have the same values in it.

```
select a.date,a.id,a.value,b.date,b.id,b.value,c.date,c.id,c.value
from table_a a
full outer join table_b on b.id = a.id
full outer join table_c on c.id = b.id
```

The above code gave the following output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buQXE.png)

I want the following output, where the date column is merged and acts as an index
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfdKb.png)

how do I get the output in the second picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce`, typicall when your work with `full join`

```
select 
  coalesce(a.date, b.date, c.date) as ddate,
  a.id,a.value,
  b.id,b.value,
  c.id,c.value
from table_a a
  full outer join table_b on b.id = a.id
  full outer join table_c on c.id = b.id
```